# XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt. Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: ios, cordova, jquery-mobile, in-app-purchase, mobile-website

Apple seems to not be liking my ajax requests. I'm trying to verify the receipt in a PhoneGap app after an in-app purchase.

```
// prepare JSON object for Apple
/* Retrieve the receipt data from the transaction’s transactionReceipt property (on iOS) or from the receipt file inside the application bundle (on OS X) and encode it using base64 encoding.
Create a JSON object with a single key named receipt-data and the string you created in step 1. Your JSON code should look like this:
{
    "receipt-data" : "(receipt bytes here)"
} */
var data = JSON.stringify({
    'receipt-data' : btoa(transactionReceipt)
});
if(DEBUG) console.log('Data: ' + data);

var url = 'https://' + (DEBUG ? 'sandbox' : 'buy') + '.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt';
if(DEBUG) console.log('URL: ' + url);

// send the POST request
/* Post the JSON object to the App Store using an HTTP POST request. The URL for the store is https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt. */
$.ajax(url, {
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('Request returned successfully.');

        // parse the response
        /*
        The response received from the App Store is a JSON object with two keys, status and receipt. It should look something like this:
        {
            "status" : 0,
            "receipt" : { (receipt here) }
        }
        If the value of the status key is 0, this is a valid receipt. If the value is anything other than 0, this receipt is invalid.
        */
        if(data.status === 0)
        console.log("Receipt is valid.");
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.error('Request failed with response code ' + errorThrown);
    }

});
```

I am using jQuery and have:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    // xss
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
}
```

Has anyone tried verifying their receipt via ajax and had this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Domain whitelisting in Apache Cordova is a security model that
>   controls access to outside domains, such as http://google.com. The
>   default security policy is to block all network access

http://docs.phonegap.com/guide_whitelist_index.md.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have whitelisted all outside domains with the `*`. Is there a special way I need to enable it for apple? All my other links work (to google analytics and such).

Comment: AFAIK it should just work. I wonder if it has something to do with http vs https. I haven't tried doing anything with https.

Comment: Doesn't the error mean that the permission is being blocked by apple? I mean, this must work because every app uses it for IAP verification, but they should be providing the `Access-Control` header. Maybe there's something I need to do on my dev machine?